# Java copy file from folder to another folder with different name

Tags: java, copy

I configured my properties file with my source path and dest path :

```
pathSource = C://Test
pathOut = C://Test//Folder
```

I try to copy this file from pathSource to pathOut (with variable `config.getValue()` :

```
Files.copy(config.getValue("pathTemplate"), config.getValue("pathOut"), REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

My 2 variables config are String why I have this error :  `Cannot resolve method 'copy(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Files.copy()` requires the first two parameters to be of type `Path`.
You need to construct those from your strings i.e.

```
Path input = Paths.get(config.getValue("pathTemplate"));
Path output = Paths.get(config.getValue("pathOut"));
Files.copy(input, output, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Answer (score 0):

Files.copy method does not accept String parameters. It accepts Path parameters. Please see the documentaion: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html
You will have to change your config.getValue to return a Path object or convert the String output into Path objects